# Running Ansible task as a specific user

Tags: permissions, sudo, ansible

I am trying to run a specific Ansible task as a different user than the one who is running the playbook. My `.yml` file looks like this:

```
---

- hosts: staging_servers
  tasks:    
    - name: check user
      remote_user: someusername
      shell: whoami
```

Running this task shows me that `whoami` command returns a different user than I defined in the task (precisely, returns the user which is defined in `hosts` file called `ubuntu`).

I also tried to define the task like this:

```
---

- hosts: staging_servers
  tasks:
    - name: check user
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: someusername
      shell: whoami
```

but then I get '`Missing sudo password`' error, although there is a line in `sudoers` file which says `someusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and issuing commands with `sudo` on remote machine as `someusername` doesn't ask me for a password.

So, how can I run the specific task as a different user which is not the user defined in `hosts` file or `root` himself?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're misunderstanding both settings there:

- [remote_user](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#remote-user) is an Ansible setting that controls the SSH user Ansible is using to connect: `ssh ${REMOTE_USER}@remotehost`
- [someusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Example_Entries) is a sudo configuration that allows the user `someusername` to execute all commands in any host without a password. It does not allow anyone to issue commands as `someusername` though.

Ideally, you would **login directly as the right user** and that's what `remote_user` is all about. But usually you are only able to login as an administrative user (say, `ubuntu`) and have to sudo commands as another user (let's say `scrapy`). Then you should leave `remote_user` to the user that logs in and the add the following ansible properties to the job:

```
- name: log in as ubuntu and do something as scrapy
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: scrapy
  shell: do-something.sh
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarifying this! But how to run a specific task as a specific user then?

Comment: Note that `remote_user` defaults to the current user in your local machine -- just as ssh does, actually.

Comment: Alright, but with a setup like this I still get '`Missing sudo password`' error. Is there a way to avoid asking for password for that specific user?

Comment: I think I found the answer, adding the line to sudoers: `ubuntu ALL=(someusername) NOPASSWD: ALL`, but I have to think about the security behind this... Is there any other way except adding this line to sudoers?

Comment: the proper way would be to let your remote user to login directly.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking in the end, just to make those tasks which should be done as `someusername` as a playbook different than the one which is using `ubuntu` user. Can you maybe include your last comment in the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It was already there, now it's there with bold.

Answer (score 44):

Note that after Ansible 1.9, the `sudo` wording was replaced with `become`, thus

```
sudo: yes
sudo_user: some_user
```

becomes (pun intended):

```
become: yes
become_user: some_user
```

See more specifics here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749788/402727

Also write this *before* the actual module (e.g. `command` or `shell`) you want to execute for it to take effect. At least in my experience it didn't work correctly if I have written `become` and `become_user` after the `shell` module.

```
- name: Example user change
  become: true
  become_user: '{{ user }}'
  shell: |
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

As ex-nerd [pointed out](https://serverfault.com/a/741058/536173) already, you have to use the [`become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) module nowadays. Further more, to get exactly what OP wants, use [`su`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/su_become.html) as the become method:

```
- name: check user
  become: yes
  become_user: someusername
  become_method: su
  become_flags: '--login'
  shell: whoami
```

`become_flags: '--login'` makes sure that you login as it would happen manually, e. g. also loading `.profile` etc.

If you did not already define a *become password* for the user who logs in to the host, you can do it at task level via `vars`:

```
- name: check user
  become: yes
  become_user: someusername
  become_method: su
  become_flags: '--login'
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: <Password of 'ubuntu' in OP's case>
  shell: whoami
```

If you login to the host using one user (with `sudo` privilege) and want to execute something as another user (that may not have a password), add the following line to the above:

```
become_exe: 'sudo -p "Password: " su -'
```